# A looped hub connected to a switch

Tags: switch, loopback, loop-device, hub

---- We don't want to block the use of Hubs ---

If two switches are connected to each other via a hub, STP detects and blocks alternate link (if available).

But if a hub is connected to even one (single) switch, and the hub is LOOPED TO ITSELF, it brings down the entire network.

So is there any way (feature) in Enterasys, that we can protect the entire network from crashing due to this one looped hub???

Comment: Try removing "Spanning Tree Protocoll" on the switches

Comment: But if I remove the STP on switch than the loop on the switch will do the same thing.